create and add custom grafana plugin
i am creating a grafana plugin (panel plugin ) to show hello world as text .
so this iw what i did exactly :

i scaffolded the plugin template using npx @grafana/create-plugin@latest .
installed dependecies using npm
builded the project using:

 npm run build 


i put the content of the dist folder in a the plugins folder of grafana (the instance of grafana that i have locally ) , path for plugins is :

C:\Program Files\GrafanaLabs\grafana\public\app\plugins\panel

so now i have in the grafana plugins folder a folder named "cni-names-panel" (just a name for the folder of my plugin )
and when i restarted grafana server i got this error in the console
 GET http://localhost:3000/core:plugin/cni-names-panel.js 404 (Not Found)  

it always does this for the name of the folder that contains the plugin
ex : if the plugin is in a folder named "PluginDemo" i would get
GET http://localhost:3000/core:plugin/PluginDemo.js 404 (Not Found)  

can someone help me please ?
this is my plugin.json :
plugin.json
dist folder

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Use [code block] instead. And more generally I advise you to [edit] your question and clean up formatting.

Issue could be related to signed/unsigned plugins.
You can change app mode to development in C:\Program Files\GrafanaLabs\grafana\conf\defaults.ini to allow loading of all plugins, including unsigned:
app_mode = development

Or allow your particular plugin:
allow_loading_unsigned_plugins = cni-names-panel


thanks a lot for your help bro , i tried 'app_mode = development' and i added the 'allow_loading_unsigned_plugins = cni-names-panel' in the grafana.ini file and it didnt work . the problem is i think that grafana is still looking for that js file that matchs the name of the folder containing the plugin like cni-names-panel.js ( GET http://localhost:3000/core:plugin/cni-names-panel.js 404 (Not Found) )
thanks for your help anyway !
